# Classification of (complex algebraic) vector bundles on punctured affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, equivariant

The [Quillen-Suslin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen%E2%80%93Suslin_theorem) theorem asserts that there are no nontrivial vector bundles over the affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, $n\geq 0$.
Let's work over the complex numbers. What can be said about vector bundles on the *punctured* affine space $X_n=\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\smallsetminus\{0\}$?
According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.0575.pdf), there seem to be room for nontrivial vector bundles.

Let $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ act on $X_n$ by the action $\lambda.(x_0,\dots,x_n):=(\lambda x_0,\lambda x_1,\dots, \lambda x_n)$ whose quotient is $\mathbb{P}^n$.
Notice that equivariant v.b. on $X_n$ are in bijection -via pullback- with v.b. on $\mathbb{P}^n$, and the latter form already a rich moduli problem on its own. In this question we concentrate on the specificity of $X_n$

> **1.** Is there some sort of classification of v.b. on $X_n$, taking as a starting base -say- the "classification" of stable v.b. on $\mathbb{P}^n$ given by the corresponding moduli spaces?
>
> What about particular ranks, for example the case of **line bundles**?
>
> **2.** Are there vector bundles on $X_n$ that are not pullbacks of v.b. on $\mathbb{P}^n$, that is, v.b. on $X_n$ that do not admit an equivariant structure?

Comment: The pullback of the tangent bundle from $\mathbb{P}^n$ is nontrivial for every $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I realize now that I should have phrased question 1. differently. Vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$ giving already a rich moduli problem, I should have probably rather concentrated on asking if there are non-equivariant bundles on $X_n$...

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Using weighted actions, you have weighted projective spaces as quotients and shouldn't they give you other vector bundles?

Comment: @Mohan: maybe they could be given by different equivariant structures on the same bundle?

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35788/extending-vector-bundles-on-a-given-open-subscheme-reprise/35829#35829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spoke to my colleague Song Sun, and he reminded me of a discussion that he and I had about Question 2 some time ago.  For $n\geq 2$, there are many examples of locally free sheaves on $X_{n} = \mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ that admit no equivariant structure.  Denote by $S$ the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x_0,\dots,x_n]$.  Denote by $S_+$ the maximal ideal $\langle x_0,\dots,x_n \rangle$.  Let $\underline{f}=(f_0,\dots,f_n)$ be a regular sequence of elements in $S_+$.

Associated to this regular sequence there is a Koszul complex $(K_\bullet(\underline{f}),d_\bullet)$ of $S$-modules where $K_0(\underline{f})$ equals $S$, where $K_1(\underline{f})$ equals $S^{\oplus(n+1)}$, where $K_r(\underline{f})$ is the $r^{\text{th}}$ exterior power of $K_1(\underline{f})$, and where $d_r:K_r(\underline{f}) \to K_{r-1}(\underline{f})$ is the unique sequence of $R$-module homomorphisms such that $d_1(g_1,\dots,g_n) = f_1g_1 + \dots + f_ng_n$ and such that $(K_{\bullet}(\underline{f}),d_\bullet)$ is a differential graded $R$-algebra.  To be precise, $d_{r-1}\circ d_r$ equals the zero homomorphism, and $d_{r+s}(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d_r(\alpha)\wedge \beta + (-1)^r\alpha\wedge d_s(\beta)$ for every $r,s\geq 0$, for every $\alpha\in K_r(\underline{f})$, and for every $\beta\in K_s(\underline{f})$.

For every integer $r\geq 1$, denote by $Z_r(\underline{f})$ the kernel of $d_r$.  Since $\underline{f}$ is a regular sequence, this is the same as the image of $d_{r+1}$.  Thus, also define $Z_0(\underline{f})$ to be the image of $d_1$, i.e., the ideal $I$ generated by $\underline{f}$.  In particular, $Z_{n+1}(\underline{f})$ is the zero module, and $Z_n(\underline{f})$ is $K_{n+1}(\underline{f})$.

**Fact 1.** For all $r$ with $1\leq r \leq n$, $Z_r(\underline{f})$ is a reflexive $S$-module.

**Proof.**  By construction $K_r(\underline{f})$ is a free $S$-module, hence reflexive, and $K_{r-1}(\underline{f})$ is torsion-free (even free).  The kernel of every $S$-module homomorphism from a reflexive module to a torsion-free module is reflexive. **QED**

**Fact 2.** For $M=Z_{n-1}(\underline{f})$, the first Fitting ideal $\text{Fitt}_1(M)$ equals the ideal $I$ generated by $(f_0,\dots,f_n)$.

**Proof.** The Fitting ideal can be computed from any finite presentation of $M$.  For $Z_{n-1}(\underline{f})$, one such presentation is $d_{n+1}:K_{n+1}(\underline{f}) \to K_n(\underline{f})$.  By self-duality of the Koszul complex, the Fitting ideal of $d_{n+1}$ is $I$. **QED**

Since the Fitting ideal is intrinsic, if $M$ is equivariant, then $I$ is a homogeneous ideal.  However, there are many $S_+$-primary ideals $I$ that are generated by a regular sequence, yet are not homogeneous ideals.  For instance, one example is $$\underline{f}=(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1}-x_n^2,x_n^3).$$ For $n\geq 2$, for such $\underline{f}$, the module $M=Z_{n-1}(\underline{f})$ is reflexive, the restriction of $\widetilde{M}$ to $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ is locally free (visibly it is locally free on each $D(f_i)$ for $i=0,\dots,n$).  Yet $\widetilde{M}$ is not equivariant since $I$ is not a homogeneous ideal.

**Edit.** Song Sun asked the following variant of the question.  For a reflexive $S$-module that is locally free on $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ and whose Fitting ideals are all homogeneous, is the module equivariant?  Also, note that every module as constructed above (also allowing other syzygy modules of the complexes) has rank $\geq n$.  So here is a second variant: is every reflexive $S$-module that is locally free on $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ equivariant provided that the rank is $\leq n-1$?

Comment: Interesting. What about line bundles? Can $M$ ever have rank $1$?

Comment: The rank of $M$ equals $n$.  Since the construction above only works for $n\geq 2$ (so that we know that $Z_{n-1}(\underline{f})$ is reflexive), it does not give examples of line bundles.

Comment: Several elementary points are worth stating explicitly: (1) Algebraic line bundles always extend uniquely over codimension $ \geq 2$ loci in smooth varieties (just take closures of the subvarieties representing the Cartier divisor class);

Comment: (2) Reflexive sheaves always extend uniquely over codimension $\geq 2$ loci in smooth varieties (see Okonek-Schneider-Spindler 1.1.12);

Comment: (3) The tangent bundle of $P^n$, pulled back to $A^{n+1} \backslash 0$, is $Z_r(f)$ in the above for $f = (x_0, \dots, x_n)$;

Comment: (4) The example given by Jason is not homogeneous for the usual grading, but it is homogeneous if $x_{n-1}$ has degree 2, so the bundle is pulled back from a weighted projective space.

Comment: One thing I don't know is whether $\pi^*E$ is trivial if and only if $E$ is a sum of line bundles, where $\pi: A^{n+1}\backslash 0 \to P^n$ is the projection.  Another is whether all vector bundles on $A^{n+1}\backslash 0$ are pulled back from some weighted projective space.  But I have not given these questions any thought.

Comment: @MichaelThaddeus  Happy New Year, and I hope that you are doing well.  "One thing I don't know ..."  The answer to the first question is positive and follows from the "graded Nakayama's Lemma".  Here is a link to a MSE answer that explains this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557402/graded-free-is-stronger-than-graded-and-free

Comment: @MichaelThaddeus  For the second question, there are $S_+$-primary ideals generated by a regular sequence that are not homogeneous for any grading: $(x_0,\dots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1}-x_n^2-x_n^3,x_n^4)$ is one example.

Answer (score 3):

Jean-Pierre Serre, [Prolongement de faisceaux analytiques coh ́erents](https://eudml.org/doc/73897), Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) 16 (1966), no. fasc. 1, 363–374. MR MR0212214 (35 #3088) p. 372 proves that there are infinitely many distinct *holomorphic* line bundles on $\mathbb{C}^2-0$.

Comment: This is now (after I edited the question) a partial answer to question 1. for the case of line bundles.

Comment: Wait but, if I understand correctly, Serre does the case of *analytic* vector bundles, which on a nonprojective variety might be rather different from the algebraic ones.

Comment: Indeed, the analytic and algebraic cases are very different here; any algebraic line bundle on $\mathbb{A}^2 - 0$ is trivial. Both algebraically and analytically, any line bundle on  $\mathbb{A}^2 - 0$ trivializes on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}$, so it is determined by the gluing function, a non-vanishing function on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$.

Comment: Algebraically, every such function is of the form $\alpha x^i y^j$ for some scalar $\alpha$, and thus can be written as the product of $\alpha x^i$, which extends to $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}$, and $y^j$, which extends to $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}$. Thus, this line bundle is trivial.

Comment: Every algebraic vector bundle on $\mathbb C^2- 0$ extends to an algebraic vector bundle on $\mathbb C^2$ (see Arapura's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35788/extending-vector-bundles-on-a-given-open-subscheme-reprise/35829#35829) and therefore must be trivial.

Comment: Analytically, $\exp(x^{-1} y^{-1})$ is an example of a non-vanishing holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ which cannot be written as a product of a function which extends to $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ and one which extends to $\mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times \mathbb{C}$, so it gives a line bundle which is holomorphically nontrivial.